# Composition of partial lenses

Tags: haskell, lenses

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to modify values nested inside of `Maybe` types (or other types for modeling partiality).

Here is the example setup:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Outer = Outer { _inner :: Maybe Inner }
  deriving (Show)

data Inner = Inner { _foo :: Int }
  deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Outer
makeLenses ''Inner
```

It's pretty easy to do this in a somewhat messy fashion with `lens`:

```
wibble :: Outer -> Maybe Outer
wibble o = do i <- view inner o
              let i' = over foo succ i
              return $ set inner (Just i') o
```

To put a point on why this is nasty, here's what I would like to be able to write:

```
wibble' :: Outer -> Maybe Outer
wibble' = overish inner.foo succ

overish = ???
```

A failure to look up a field should just make the whole operation fail, rather than making me explicitly check for failure at each point where it might happen.

Any suggestions? I've tried navigating the various `lens` modules, but nothing has quite appeared to fit the bill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `over (inner.traverse.foo)` to write to the nested field. This will not report failure the way you want though, because it succeeded in mapping over all 0 targets.

`traverse` (from `Data.Traversable`, re-exported by `Control.Lens`) here gives you a `Traversal` for walking over the `Maybe`.

You can read from it with `(^?)` to see if the target of the lens exists.

We can solve this in several ways by using existing lens combinators to read and write separately, but we could just build such a combinator directly:

```
import Data.Monoid (Any(..))
import Control.Monad (guard)

overish :: LensLike ((,) Any) s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> Maybe t
overish l f s = case l (\a -> (Any True, f a)) s of
  (Any r, t) -> t <$ guard r
```

You could write this with `l %%~ \a -> (Any True, f a)` as well.

You can easily check if a `Traversal` has no targets by using `nullOf`, but this will require two passes and a higher rank type:

```
overish :: Traversal s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> Maybe t
overish l f s = over l f s <$ guard (not (nullOf l s))
```

This is effectively just checking to see that there is a target and then applying the setter to it if there are targets.

Then you can just use

```
overish (inner.traverse.foo) succ
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to just use the standard combinators, but the second definition looks like what I want. I'll have to study the first a bit more, though; I don't quite get why the tuple is being introduced there.

Comment: there we're picking the `Applicative` we invoke your `Traversal` with to be `(,) Any`. This lets you extract not only the updated answer but a monoidal summary of values of type Any, because `(,) e` is applicative when `e` is a `Monoid`. Here `mempty = Any False`, `mappend` will `||` together values, so when we find something the auxillary answer goes to `Any True`, otherwise it stays `Any False`.

Comment: This is, of course, just a trick to do it all in one pass. ;)

Comment: This combinator came up a few more times and was added to the library as `failover
  :: MonadPlus m =>
     LensLike ((,) Any) s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> m t`